# NSMutableArray always converting to NSArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray that did its initialisation like follows:

```
@interface Countries ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayofCountry;
}
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
       //...
       arrayofCountry=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       //...
}
```

Then I wanted to apply a `removeObjectAtIndex` to that NSMutableArray:

```
[arrayofCountry removeObjectAtIndex:sourceRow];
```

The problem is it is crashing with that log:

```
-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I verified it with:

```
NSLog( NSStringFromClass( [arrayofCountry class] ));
```

and it's returning `__NSArrayI`.
The question is how it was converted to NSArray? 
I'm just populating it with:

```
arrayofCountry=[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"];
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `arrayofCountry = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: The problem lies in your last code bit. arrayOfCountry = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"]; does NOT populate it. It replaces it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. This will create a new `NSMutableArray` based on the contents of your other array.

```
arrayofCountry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"]];
```

Comment: If you need a retained version you can do the same thing with [[NSMutablArray alloc] initWithArray: ];

If DCGoD's answer is correct, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

If the value stored in the JSON file with the key `country_name` is an `NSArray` then it can't be copied into an `NSMutableArray` without changing it. Try doing this:

```
arrayofCountry = [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"] mutableCopy];
```

Also, when creating your `NSMutableArray` create it like this (instead of using *alloc* and then *init*):

```
arrayOfCountry = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: It worked too. So the problem is that I was getting an array from the JSON and applying it to an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @androniennn Correct! And that's why you were getting a crash, and the change in pointer type. Accept the answer that best resolves the problem and explains it. :-)

Comment: @androniennn Even though you overwrite later on, every other answer is missing this technically important bit `arrayOfCountry = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
arrayofCountry=(NSMutableArray *)[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"];
```

as @ Ahmed Mohammed:suggested try like this way

```
arrayofCountry=[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: tried it right now and it's always crashing at `removeObjectAtIndex`.

Comment: are you getting same crash description?

Comment: casting the pointer does not change the underlying object's class!! Instead you should try `arrayofCountry=[[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"country_name"] mutableCopy];`